# TypeError when creating netcdf file

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, netcdf

I am trying to creat a netcdf file. In the first step all I want is to read the data from a netcdf file and write it in a new netcfd file I have a data-array, that has the dtype float64 and three dimensions (time, latitude, longitude).

When I run the script I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching
> types dtype('U32') dtype('U32') dtype('U32')

I understand, that somehow the datatypes don't match. But I don't see where the problem is.

```
fid = Dataset(Dir, "r")
t2m = np.array(fid.variables["t2m"])

#create new netcdf file
new_file = "ERA_t2m_2011to2017"
dataset = Dataset(new_file, "w", format="NETCDF3_64BIT_OFFSET")

#create dimensions
longitude = dataset.createDimension("longitude", 1200)
latitude = dataset.createDimension("latitude", 101)
time = dataset.createDimension("time", None)

#create variables
newvar = dataset.createVariable("longitude", np.float32, ("longitude"))
newvar.long_name = "longitude"
newvar.units = "degrees_east"
newvar.axis = "longitude-axis"
newvar[:] = np.array(fid.variables["longitude"])

newvar = dataset.createVariable("latitude", np.float32, ("latitude"))
newvar.long_name = "latitude"
newvar.units = "degrees_north"
newvar.axis = "latitude-axis"
newvar[:] = np.array(fid.variables["latitude"])

newvar = dataset.createVariable("time", np.int32, ("time"))
newvar.long_name = "time"
newvar.units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0"
newvar.calendar = "gregorian"
newvar.axis = "time-axis"
newvar[:] = np.array(fid.variables["time"])

newvar = dataset.createVariable("t2m", np.float64, ("time", "latitude", "longitude"))
newvar.long_name = "2 meter temperature"
newvar.units = "K"
newvar.FillValue = "-32767"
newvar.scale_factor = "0.00137038771743"
newvar.add_offset = "238.393472216"
newvar.missing_value = "-32767"
newvar[:] = t2m
```

Maybe an important information is also, that

```
fid.variables["t2m"]
```

yields the following output:

> class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'
>
> int16 t2m(time, latitude, longitude)
>
> scale_factor: 0.00135205961432
>
> add_offset: 238.864955074
>
> _FillValue: -32767
>
> missing_value: -32767
>
> units: K
>
> long_name: 2 metre temperature
>
> unlimited dimensions: time
> current shape = (2920, 101, 1200)
> filling off

So the 2tm variable seems to be the dtype int32 at first, but it turns to be float64 when I read it in.
However both creating the variable 2tm as float64 or as int32 leads to the same error.

Can you help me out here?
Thank you.

Comment: Seems odd that the 2-meter temperature is an integer. But anyhow, please add the full trace, at least the part which mentions which line results in the `TypeError`. So far I don't see anything wrong with your code, usually, Numpy/NetCDF4 is quite flexible in casting things to the correct data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you specify:

```
newvar.FillValue = "-32767"
newvar.scale_factor = "0.00137038771743"
newvar.add_offset = "238.393472216"
newvar.missing_value = "-32767"
```

`scale_factor` and `add_offset` should be numerical values, not strings. `FillValue` and `missing_value` can be strings (at least, in my small test), but you probably want to make them numerical as well.

From the documentation:

> When data is written to a variable it is packed using::
>
> data = (data - self.add_offset)/self.scale_factor

This is where the error comes from, for example:

```
np.array(1.)-'string'
```

Results in the exact same error as you get.